# How can I verify that a user enters an integer or alphabetic character in Java?

Tags: java

I am accepting an input from user as an integer using `Scanner.nextInt()`. How do I verify that he enters an integer, and not an alphabetic character?

Answer (score 2):

The `nextInt()` method will throw an `InputMismatchException` if the input is not an int. So you could catch that exception and perform a conditional operation. Alternatively, checkout the `hasNextInt()` which will return a boolean indicating whether the next value is an int.

```
if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
  int i = scanner.nextInt();
} else {
  System.out.println("Not an int");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a try / catch. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572160/infinite-looptry-catch-with-exceptions) post.

```
try {

      num = reader.nextInt();


    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
         System.out.println("Invalid value!");
}
```

Also, if you notice, in the post this is wrapped up in a loop until a valid integer is input.

Answer (score 1):

It will throw an exception if int is not entered as input. Just catch that exception and now you know the user has entered an unparsable value.

[Scanner.nextInt()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

If a user enters an alphabet and you expect an int, you can test for the int with [Scanner.hasNextInt()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29) and if it is false message the user.

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int i;
System.out.print("Insert an integer number: ");

while(true)
{
    try
    {
        i = input.nextInt();
        break;
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e)
    {
        System.out.print("You have to insert an integer number, try again: ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use a try catch block if there is an Exception if it's not an int.

```
try {
    int aInt = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
}  catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    //handler-code
}
```