# exceptions and infinite loops

Tags: java, inputmismatchexception

```
    // Precondition: number provided is a positive integer
    // Postcondition: returns a integer of length 4
     public static int validateNumber(int num, Scanner scan)
{
    int number = num;
    while(number < 1000 || number > 9999)
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.print("Number must be 4 digits long. Please provide the number again: ");
            number = scan.nextInt();    // reads next integer provided                                      
            scan.nextLine();
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e) //outputs error message if value provided is not an integer
        {
            System.out.println("Incorrect input type.");
        }
    }
    return number;
}
```

Assuming the preconditions are met, when this method gets executed and after entering a 
string to test the program, I get an infinite loop. Why is this problem occurring and how would I fix it?

Comment: have you confirmed the length of the numbers you are entering

Comment: Have you tried printing number after assigning it the next value to check it's reading ok?

Comment: how about debugging it?

Comment: @Alan What is the scanner that you're providing in the input. Is it new Scanner(System.in)

Comment: @Alan Then it shouldn't be a problem. The program will prompt you to re-enter the number. If you enter a four-digit number, the method returns.

Comment: This is what I said. His code works fine. Just called it with `int num = validateNumber(12345, new Scanner(System.in));` and looped until I wrote 1234.

Comment: I think i wasn't too clear on what I planned to do. Yes the code works fine but I'm trying to cover for the exception when a string is provided AFTER method execution. That's when I get the infinite loop

Comment: @Sergi I was the first up-voter of your comment "Works fine for me" :-). I was thinking if the OP was wrapping the Scanner over a gazillion-line file or a socket.

Comment: For instance:
Please provide a number: 12111
Number must be 4 digits long. Please provide the number again: alan

Comment: @Alan Ahh.. I get it now, just put a number = scan.nextLine(); in the exception block as well.

Comment: yup works for me but it's actually just scan.nextLine()

Comment: Does `-123` count as four digits?

Comment: @David Wallace I didn't realize that but yes it is

Comment: Edited above to account for only positive integers for return value

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572160/infinite-looptry-catch-with-exceptions?rq=1 for further explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid infinite loop when the exception is thrown, you must skip the current line and move on to the next line for processing. Currently, when the exception is thrown, you are re-iterating and scanning the same line which again throws exception and hence you are stuck in infinite loop.

I think you need to write the `scan.nextLine()` method call when an exception is thrown.

```
catch (InputMismatchException e) // outputs error message if value provided is not an integer
            {
                System.out.println("Incorrect input type.");
                // Moved the nextLine() method call over here
                scan.nextLine();
            }
```

Also modify the logic to detect if the number is 4 digit or not. Use integer comparison using`<` and `>` instead of converting the number into string.

Comment: an explanation of what and why you are changing is more of an answer than just code : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques

Answer (score 2):

Why not

```
number < 1000 || number > 9999
```

instead of

```
String.valueOf(number)).length() != 4
```

It looks much cleaner and is probably more efficient.

Comment: Sorry, how does this address the issue of the "method going into an infinite loop"

Answer (score 0):

Code looks OK, but consider this instead:

```
while ((int)Math.log10(number) != 3)
```

Comment: I believe you mean 3, not 4.

Comment: I also worry about what happens if a negative number finds its way in.

Answer (score 0):

One problem i can see just see your try catch block carefully-

If you input a non-integer input then scanner.nextInt() will throw an InputMisMatchException
and the control will come to catch block so finally a new value is not assigned to the number
so again condition met for because its  checking with the previous number itself.

Just try if it works if it doesn't then please send your input cases so that we can analyze and also tell us what is the initial value of num in method you are passing.