# An infinite loop owing to recursion (introductory)

Tags: java, recursion, infinite-loop

I was trying to write a method that enables one to input integers via Scanner without the program crashing due to exceptions. Here's what I initially had:(here, sc is a Scanner object)

```
    public static int inputInt(String message) {                                            
    int returnval = 0;
    System.out.println(message);
    try {
        returnval = sc.nextInt();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("You must enter an integer.");
        inputInt(message);
    }
    return returnval;
}
```

When I tested the program with an invalid input, an infinite loop was initiated, with the message and "You must enter an integer" being printed many times before being halted by Eclipse.
I fixed this using the following code:

```
 public static int inputInt(String message) { 
    int returnval = 0;
    System.out.println(message);
    String valstring = sc.nextLine();
    try {
        returnval = Integer.parseInt(valstring);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("You must enter an integer.");
        inputInt(message);
    }
    return returnval;
}
```

Why does the first method fail, but not the second? Might there be a cleaner way to accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741189/exceptions-and-infinite-loops

Comment: The basic reason is this: if you tell the scanner to look for an integer, and it sees a character that doesn't belong in an integer, it throws an exception, but that character is still there in the input.  You have to do something to force the scanner to skip over it before asking it to try again.  `sc.nextLine()` (see Doorknob of Snow's answer) will do the job.

Comment: note that if you use `nextInt()`, there is a _newline character_ left in your input.

Comment: @RafaEl True.  But also note that if the next `nextInt()` sees the newline, it will skip over it, because `nextInt()` looks at tokens and whitespace characters such as newlines are (by default) not part of tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

`Scanner.nextInt()` has the capacity of throwing 3 exceptions:

1- `InputMismatchException`: Thrown when the next item isn't an `int`. 
2- `NoSuchElementException`: When there isn't a next anything. 
3- `IllegalStateException`: If the `Scanner` has been closed.

So when you enter an illegal value, such as "abc" for example, the top piece of code does this:

Takes "abc" and tries to convert it to an int. (`nextInt()`). Because "abc" isn't a number, it cannot convert, and throws an `InputMismatchException`. However, beacuse the method didn't complete successfully, "abc" is left as the next item to be read. Because the exception was thrown, the code inside your `catch` block is run. It prints out "You must enter an integer." Then it calls itself again, passing itself `message`. It then initialises `returnval` and prints out the same `message` from the first run, because you passed it to yourself again. Then you enter the `try` block, where, because "abc" wasn't read successfully and left there, the scanner reads "abc" and tries to convert it to an `int` again. Of course, this won't work, and the cycle starts again.

### Solution

Now you know what your problem is, you can figure out a solution. The most elegant in my mind would be to use the `Scanner` method, `hasNextInt()`. This will return a `boolean` letting you know if the next item to be read can be converted to an `int`. For example, if the next item is "abc", the method will return `false`. For the next item "1", the method will return `true`. So, if you modify your code like so, it should work:

```
public static int inputInt(String message) {                                            
    int returnval = 0;
    System.out.println(message);
    while(!sc.hasNextInt()) {
        sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You must enter an integer.");
    }
    returnval = sc.nextInt();
    return returnval;
}
```

What this code does:

1- Initializes `returnval` and prints out `message`. 
2- Enters the while loop as long as the scanner doesn't have an `int` to read. Effectively "waiting" for the next `int` to be input. 
3- Once it has an `int` to read, it reads the int and saves the value in `returnval`. 
4- It returns `returnval` to the caller.

(Slow and steady wins the race, lol. I always seem to be the slow one to answer. Maybe because I write small novels as answers.... ;))

Comment: That's great! I liked how your answer was very comprehensive, don't change your style :)

Comment: How does one use hasNextInt() so that it considers the validity of the entire input, rather than just the first token entered?

Comment: @Ayesha In what sense? If the next few characters to be read are "365" then the `int` that will be read, (because the code will validate that as an `int` and proceed to read it), will be 365. A "token" can be defined as a string of characters that are significant in a group. In this case, the token for the above input is "365", not just the single character "3".

Comment: The input 5 5 5 is the one I used - I want such an input to be rejected.

Comment: Hmm..I tested that input. All it does is return the first "5" as an `int`. If you don't want it do so, I guess you could use `Scanner.findInLine(" ")` to look for any spaces in the entire line before you even try to parse an `int`. If so, you can return without parsing.

Comment: Of course. The JavaDocs are infinitely helpful for things like this. That's where I found the `findInLine()` method. The JavaDoc for Scanner is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a cleaner way: use `hasNextInt`:

```
public static int inputInt(String message) {
    System.out.println(message);
    while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
        sc.nextLine(); // clear the bad input first

        System.out.println("You must enter an integer.");
        System.out.println(message); // why use recursion? just use a while loop
    }
    return sc.nextInt();
}
```

The changes I made:

- Uses `hasNextInt`, so you don't have to use exceptions
- Added `sc.nextLine();` (the root of your problem)
- Instead of recursion, just does a while loop (why recurse when you can simple loop?)
- Eliminated temporary variable
- Made it more readable (IMO)

Comment: One question here, though. The input 5 5 5 (three fives with spaces between) is accepted by this method. Is this a problem with my program?

Comment: @Ayesha That's because `hasNextInt` simple takes the next token (which would be 5). If you don't want that, call `nextLine` and test if it's a valid int.

Comment: This would be done via something like what is shown here, correct?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439529/determine-if-a-string-is-an-integer-in-java