# beginner: exception thrown in catch; implement a loop? - Java

Tags: java

Developing a program that is similar to creating receipts. It takes scanner inputs: name and price. Trying to Use a try - catch for the situation where a double would not be inputted into the price scanner. Managed to get this to work, but for only if an exception is thrown once; and if I give incorrect input again inside the catch block it will fail. What could I do to have the program handle exceptions inside the catch? I'm also just a kid learning with whichever free resources I can get, so the error here might just be fundamental problems/bad coding practice and would like those to be pointed out as well.

Thank You!

Here is the code:

```
        Scanner scanPrice = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the cost: ");
        try {
            priceTag = scanPrice.nextDouble();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Only numbers. Enter the cost again.");
            scanPriceException = new Scanner(System.in);
            priceTag = scanPriceException.nextDouble();
        }

        costs[i] = priceTag;
```

Comment: I don't think you can edit until you reach a certain rep points, so keep trying. Also, it would be nice if you isolated the part you want to ask and not posting the whole file.

Comment: You should catch the exception in the try/catch block, then, as your program goals require, exit the try/catch block and try again either by looping through that block or by falling into a different try/catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because your `try` and `catch` block is run only once. You need to put it in a loop if you need to retry until success. Simply change your code block:

```
    Scanner scanPrice = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the cost: ");
    try {
        priceTag = scanPrice.nextDouble();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Only numbers. Enter the cost again.");
        scanPriceException = new Scanner(System.in);
        priceTag = scanPriceException.nextDouble();
    }
```

To:

```
    Scanner scanPrice = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter the cost: ");
        try {
            priceTag = scanPrice.nextDouble();
            break;
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Only numbers. Enter the cost again.");
            scanPrice.next();
        }
    }
```

The `try` block will not reach `break` statement if there is an `InputMismatchException` is thorwn on `nextDouble` .

EDIT: Forgot to add but you also need to discard the old input so it won't raise the exception again. Hence the `scanPrice.next()` at the end. See this answer for more details: [How to handle infinite loop caused by invalid input using Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572160/infinite-looptry-catch-with-exceptions?rq=1)

Comment: thanks, an avast add-on didn't let me click edit. Your answer is the solution. My problem was trying to use a do while, but didn't know what condition to put into while. Could the while (true) be explained a bit?

Comment: While `true` simply means you run the loop for indefinitely until explicitly `break` out of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Here, **while(*true*)** means that until your scanner is not getting the desired input(which is a double value in this case) it will keep asking you "**Only numbers. Enter the cost again.**".
The moment the scanner gets the correct input then in that case no "**InputMismatchException**" will be thrown and the break statement in the try block will be executed, which takes your programs control to out of the **while** loop.