# Try-catch only loops once

Tags: java, try-catch

I have a try-catch that is meant to catch anything that is not an integer. When I enter a non integer (e.g. 5.6) it tells me only integers are allowed and lets me try again (as it should). But if I enter a non-integer again it doesn't say anything and will keep taking inputs, leaving output blank.

```
if (choicesObjects == b) {
    System.out.println("TEST 2");            
    System.out.println("Object: Right triangle");
    System.out.println("\nEnter length of Right triangle: ");

    int lengthOfTriangle = 0;  
    try {                 
        lengthOfTriangle = input.nextInt();         
    } catch(InputMismatchException e) {        
        System.out.println("\nError: user input must be an integer greater than 0.\n");
        System.out.println("Object: Right triangle");
        System.out.println("\nEnter length of Right triangle: ");
        input.next();                
    }
    //method stuff
}
```

Comment: try/catch isn't a loop. You'd need to use a loop if you want it to loop.

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: You need to do something like this: while(condition not met){ get user input}

Comment: You need to first look up the tutorials on try / catch and loops, as this site is not meant to be a substitute for this crucial and important step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `try/catch` statement is not a loop. It will always be executed once.

Of course, if there is a loop inside the `try` block, that block will keep executing until terminated. But such a loop requires an explicit command like `while` or `for` to be used.

Apparently what happens when entering a non-integer value (e.g., 5.6), is that the `nextInt()` statement throws an Exception and goes to the `catch` block. A better explanation can be given if the full code of the method is provided.

Answer (score 3):

For this you could define a function, something like this should work

```
private int getNextInt(Scanner input) {
    boolean isInt = false;
    int userInput;
    while(!isInt) {
        try {
            userInput = Integer.valueOf(input.next());
            isInt = true;
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            // Do nothing with the exception
        }
    }
    return userInput;
}
```

This should run until an input given was an int and then return said int

Comment: you have to consume the invalid token in the catch too, otherwise it is stuck in an infinite loop. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572160/how-to-handle-infinite-loop-caused-by-invalid-input-using-scanner)

Comment: @Mikenno You got compensated ... and honestly: deleting not so good answers is great practice. p1 just for doing that !

Comment: @GhostCat thanks, i believe that good ansswers are the most important thing :)

Comment: True. At some point you realize that reputation and badges matter too; but that is a rabbit hole, and kills your social life. So avoid going down that path ;-)

Answer (score 2):

something like this

```
Boolean check = true;
      
while (check) {
  if choicesObjects == b {
    System.out.println("TEST 2");
    System.out.println("Object: Right triangle");
    System.out.println("\nEnter length of Right triangle: ");

    int lengthOfTriangle = 0;

    try {
      lengthOfTriangle = input.nextInt();
    } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
      System.out.println("\nError: user input must be an integer greater than 0.\n");
      check = false;
                    
      System.out.println("Object: Right triangle");System.out.println("\nEnter length of Right triangle:");
      input.next();
    }

    //method stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: you have to consume the invalid token in the catch too. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572160/how-to-handle-infinite-loop-caused-by-invalid-input-using-scanner)

Comment: Please put some time into formatting your answer. This is a mess.

Comment: userInput = Integer.parseInt(input.next());

Comment: this because scanner or System.in as string par default you need parse this value and put .trim to make sure all spaces be removed

Answer (score 1):

You can update your code to something like this -

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = 0;
    while(true) {
        try{
            num = in.nextInt();
            break;
        }catch(Exception e){
            //print statements
            System.out.println("Try again");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Done");
```

Comment: did you test this ? Because this doesn't work for me [here](https://ideone.com/hHktSE). Just gets stuck in an infinite loop, printing `Try again`

Comment: Yes, @Shashwat. I confirmed the execution of the above code.

Comment: check the link I just gave

Comment: So, sometimes there are carriage returns (\n) being executed and which is resulting in this condition. Try implementing it on your IDE instead :)
Meanwhile, I am editing your code and trying to fix it...

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. The Problem is you have to consume the invalid token in the `catch`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572160/how-to-handle-infinite-loop-caused-by-invalid-input-using-scanner)

Comment: That is an excellent reference. I never thought about consuming the invalid tokens. Thanks for correcting me here.

Comment: "I never thought about consuming the invalid tokens" If there were no invalid tokens, there'd be no need for the loop...