# Try Catch InputMismatchException not actually catching my Error

Tags: java, inputmismatchexception

I have copied the exact same code from another program. Whenever inputting deliberate incorrect results the InputMismatchException still occurs and the program crashes.

```
import java.util.*;
    public class Runner{
    public static void main (String args[]){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    sc.useDelimiter("\n");
    Fixture f = new Fixture();
    boolean inputValid = false;
    int choice = 0;
    do{
        do {
            System.out.println("\f\t\tFootball Database");
            System.out.println("A utility to help make footballing events easier to manage.");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("\t> Press 1 to manage players ");
            System.out.println("\t> Press 2 to manage teams");
            System.out.println("\t> Press 3 to manage coaches");
            System.out.println("\t> Press 4 to manage fixtures");
            System.out.println("\t> Press 5 to save database to file");
            System.out.println("\t> Press 6 to load database from file");
            System.out.println("\t> Press 7 to terminate program");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("©Thomas Camilleri 2017");
            try{
                choice = sc.nextInt();
                inputValid = true;
            }catch(InputMismatchException e){
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
                inputValid = false;
                sc.nextInt();
                sc.nextInt();
            }
        }while(inputValid == false);
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Describe what you expect to happen and what actually happens with the necessary details.

Comment: I ran the program and inputted letters instead of integers to check if the catch was working. The program showed me the InputMismatchException error anyways, regardless of my try-catch block.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3572160/

Comment: I'm not getting an infinite loop

Comment: Read the answer to that question. The problem is that, if an `InputMismatchException` is thrown, the token is not consumed.

Comment: If you can explain in simpler terms it would be helpful, my english is a bit limited when it comes to java.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the salient part of your code:

```
        try {
            choice = sc.nextInt();   // NOT HERE
            inputValid = true;
        } catch(InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
            inputValid = false;
            sc.nextInt();            // HERE
            sc.nextInt();
        }
```

If you look at the stacktrace that you got, and look at the line numbers, you will see that the line in your code where the exception happens is the one I have tagged with `// HERE`.

(Compile and run the original program and look at the stacktrace to see what I mean.  Compare the line numbers in the stack trace with the source code.)

As you can see, that line is NOT in the `try { ... }` block.  It is in the exception handler block.

What has happened is that you have caught the exception that was thrown at the line tagged `// NOT HERE`, and then you have called `sc.nextInt()` again (at `// HERE`).  The second call has simply attempted to read *the same input characters again*.

The behavior of the `nextInt` method is as follows:

- get characters sufficient to form a token
- attempt to convert the entire token into an integer (using base-10 integer syntax)
- if the conversion succeeds, return the converted integer
- if the conversion fails, put all of the characters back and then throw an exception.

I strongly encourage you to carefully read the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for the `Scanner` class so that you understand what the methods you are using actually do.

So ... as you see ... if you just call `nextInt()` after a failed `nextInt()` call, you just get the same failure repeated.

The reason that second exception is not caught is that it has not been thrown within the `try { ... }` block.

Solution:  Instead of calling `nextInt()` in the handler, you should call a method that is going to just *discard* the rubbish.  In this case, the most sensible thing to do is to throw away everything up to the next end-of-line.

Hint #1: the `nextLine()` gets everything up to the next end-of-line.  Read the javadocs for that method too.

Hint #2: if you understand what I said, you will know where to put your modification.

Comment: Thank you for this reply. I can say I've finally understood and got my program to work successfully. Thank you very much, this was explained excellently

Answer (score -1):

Try like:

```
choice = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
```

and your program will like this:

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {

    sc.useDelimiter("\n");
//    Fixture f = new Fixture();
    boolean inputValid = false;
    int choice = 0;

//    removed outer do..while(); loop

    do {
        System.out.println("\f\t\tFootball Database");
        System.out.println("A utility to help make footballing events easier to manage.");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("\t> Press 1 to manage players ");
        System.out.println("\t> Press 2 to manage teams");
        System.out.println("\t> Press 3 to manage coaches");
        System.out.println("\t> Press 4 to manage fixtures");
        System.out.println("\t> Press 5 to save database to file");
        System.out.println("\t> Press 6 to load database from file");
        System.out.println("\t> Press 7 to terminate program");
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.print("Enter your choice : ");
        try{
//    Always use nextLine() if you mix String and basic Datatype
            choice = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
            inputValid = true;
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
            inputValid = false;
//    Removed unnecessary two sc.nextInput() lines
        }
    }while(inputValid == false);

    System.out.println("choice is : " + choice);
}
```

Comment: Got a different error in the console this time;
 
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "a"

Comment: @ThomCamilleri I have just edited the answer, watch it.

Comment: Then i keep getting "invalid input", even when i input an integer.

Comment: @ThomCamilleri I have removed one outer do{...}while(); loop and you only concentrate to specially on 4 lines after input to choice variable, because this source is tested and if this is helpful learn [how to mark answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: This is a poor answer.  You have not explained what the problem in his original code was.  Instead, you have just given him an alternative version, which he has copy-and-pasted ... and not learned anything.

Comment: @StephenC I have just given the comment and now going to edit the answer.