# Not able to recover from InputMismatchException

Tags: java, exception

I am learning about java try catch and using the following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = null;
    int i = 0;

    try {
        in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        i = in.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
        System.out.printf("%nPlease enter a number: %d", in.nextInt());
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Finally block !!!");
            in.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Running those program and input a string return java with stack trace and exit (not asking for user to input correct number).
If i remove in.nextInt() inside catch block, I do not see stack trace but not asking for user input too - exit immediately.

I can't figure it out what is wrong with my code

Comment: A try catch block is not a loop

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't be using exception handling as part of your implementation logic. It is to be used to handle exceptional scenarios outside your expectation.

Comment: Read the javadocs for `nextInt`.  If the method call throws `InputMismatchException`, it does not skip the characters making up the token that it it couldn't parse as an integer.  So if you call `nextInt` again you will attempt to parse the same token *again* as an integer ... and fail *again*.

Comment: @user3437460 - If the OP's goal is to learn how exceptions / handlers work, then this is just fine.  And besides, it is hard to make a judgment that something is an "exceptional scenario" or not without a significant amount of context.  More context than we have here.

Comment: J. Doem - also look at what your `printf` is actually doing.  It is (trying to) read a number, and then inserting that numbet into the message which is asking to enter a number.  That's not correct ... is it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`try catch finally` block works like this:

1. Execute the code in `try` block, in this case, let the user enter something.
2. If exceptions which specified in `catch` are thrown, then execute the code in `catch` block only **once**.
3. Execute the code in `finally` block.

If you want to wait until the user input an `int`, you should use `for` or `while` loop:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
int i;

while (true) {
    try {
        i = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Your input is " + i);
        break;
    } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number:");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use `Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine())` instead of `in.nextInt()`?

Comment: @J.Doem See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572160/how-to-handle-infinite-loop-caused-by-invalid-input-inputmismatchexception-usi