# How to set loop

Tags: java, loops

I'm still new in java, I want to set while loop for int year such as the year is not equal to any input string. How should i do?

This is my code:

```
int year = input.nextInt();

while (year < 1400 || year > 2600) {
    System.out.println("Invalid year, please enter again: ");
    year = input.nextInt();
}
```

[image]

Comment: You have to catch the exception. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3572233/133203) on how to handle it.

Comment: Use `nextLine()` to read the input. Then attempt to parse it `Integer.parseInt(...)`. Try-catch the `NumberFormatException`. Break out of the loop if no exception, continue if it happens.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to make use of Exception handling. Also, scan the input using **nextLine()** method and parse the using **Integer.parseInt()** method.

Make use of appropriate exception that is thrown when the string is invalid (**NumberFormatException** in this case).

Have a look at the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Solution{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        
        int yearInValidIntergerForm;
        
        while (true) {
            
            String year = input.nextLine();
            try{
                
                yearInValidIntergerForm = Integer.parseInt(year);
                
                if(yearInValidIntergerForm<1400 || yearInValidIntergerForm>2600){
                    //Custom exception - this is optional. As an alternative, you can just print invalid message instead of throwing exception.
                     
                    throw new Exception("Invalid range for input year.");
                }
                
                System.out.println("Success"); 
                
                break;
                
            }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                
                System.out.println("Input is not a valid integer.");    
                
            }catch(Exception e){
                
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Input:**

```
bgsd
3400
1500
```

**Output:**

```
Input is not a valid integer.
Invalid range for input year.
Success
```

Answer (score -1):

The user input should match the int input type. Use a try-catch block to avoid exceptions when entering String inputs.

```
try{
    while (year < 1400 || year > 2600) {
      System.out.println("Invalid year, please enter again: ");
      year = input.nextInt();
    }
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```